# Winforms button properties

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am currently using windows forms application in visual studio. I want to change button and textbox properties programmatically and not use the the properties tab. How do i do this? Is there a way to access the code of the UI of that button/Textbox after it is changed in the properties tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can change that programmatically. If you have for example a button called `btnStart`, then you have in your form access to all properties:

```
btnStart.Text = "start";
```

Have also a look at: [Change properties of programmatically created buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941583/change-properties-of-programmatically-created-buttons)

**EDIT:**

If you change it programmatically after the `InitializeComponent();` it will override changed properties set manually in the properties tab.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And in fact it's always done in code -- Properties window (i.e. VS winforms designer) just writes some code *for you*.  You can see that code when you delve into the `InitializaComponent()` method call in the form's constructor (right click InitializeComporent and select "Go to definition").

Anytime after this `InitializeComponent()` call, you can add code to change what you want:

```
 public Form1()
 {
      InitializeComponent();
      button1.Text = "Go!";
 }
```